# Here I am comparing the two activities please tell me which is the correct sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. Teachers should pay as much attention to students study as they are paying to students dance.
> 2. Teachers should pay as much attention to students study as much they are paying to students dance.

Comment: Neither is a good sentence. Are the students dancers who also study academics?

Comment: students -> students', you need the plural possessive.

Comment: You will benefit from study of the [Saxon genitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive) and the possessive generally.

Answer (score 1):

Native speaker here. As Willow Rex said, neither is completely correct. The first one is closer, but there are some bigger issues to address first.

First, the word "students" isn't quite right as used. Some correct alternatives:

1. each student's (singular)
2. their students' (plural)
3. (or, simply) students'

"Students" as you're using it just means "more than one student". But I think you mean "the activities performed *by the students*" -- which means you need to use some sort of possessive to indicate that the activities *belong to* the students.

Second, "study" and "dance" are not verbs in this case. You are not saying that the students are dancing or studying right now -- you are talking about the "output" of those actions. You are talking about their *studying* and *dancing*. ("Studies" is also an acceptable replacement for "studying".)

So, with those two issues resolved, the original 2 options read as:

1. Teachers should pay as much attention to their students' studying as they are paying to their students' dancing.
2. Teachers should pay as much attention to their students' studying as much they are paying to their students' dancing.

The first one is correct. You don't need the 2nd "much", since "much" already acts to compare two things.

"I have as much X as I have Y" means that I have the same amount of X and Y.

One other tweak to improve the sentence would be to make sure the verbs match up. Both original sentences have "should pay" and "are pay**ing**" in the same sentence. So if we match those verbs, we have:

"Teachers should pay as much attention to their students' studying as they pay to their students' dancing."

Comment: I was in the middle of writing pretty much the same thing when I noticed this answer appear.  Since mine would have added nothing not already said here, Matt gets an up vote.

Comment: can not I use "dance" in place of the word "dancing"?